# Is there a workaround for a terraform count on a resource that is only determined after an apply?

Tags: terraform, race-condition, terraform-provider-aws

In a terraform module, I had a local that used to create route53 valiation records for all SANs in an ACM certificate.

```
locals {
  my_domains = [ "some.net", "foo.com", "yack.meep" ]
  validation_domains = [for k, v in aws_acm_certificate.this.domain_validation_options : tomap(v) if contains(local.my_domains, v.domain_name)]
}
```

From the above, `validation_domains` contains a list of all the hostnames on the certificate (i.e. all my_domains with the records needed to validate them), which I can use in a count with r53 records to validate. However, I'd like to filter this list with a list of domains that are in r53:

```
locals {
  cert_domains = [ "some.net", "foo.com", "*.yack.meep" ]
  r53_domains = [ "some.net", "yack.meep" ] 
  valiation_domains = distinct(flatten([
    for k, v in aws_acm_certificate.this.domain_validation_options : [
       for verify in local.r53_domains : tomap(v) if length(regexall("${verify}$", v.domain_name)) > 0
    ]
  ]))
}
```

This would now only return ACM validations on domains that end with items from `local.r53_domains` - however, because I'm using the `regexall` function (or is it the `length` function?) with the ACM return value, I get the error:

```
   count = length(local.validation_domains)

The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
```

Besides creating targets with `-target`, are there any approaches that could be considered that could apply the filtering after provisioning? A sort of "lazy" resolution some how?

This is happening in TF 0.13.x, not sure if there's any features in later versions that might help....

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule here is that you need to write an expression which ends up with a list of a known length, even if the values *within* the list aren't fully known. That will mean that `length(...)` will then return a known number, which is good enough for `count` to know how many instances of the resource you are declaring.

This rule also applies to `for_each`, but in a slightly different way: the length of a map can be known if all of the *keys* are known, and so can safely use a map whose *values* are unknown as long as we have a known value for all the keys.

For `aws_acm_certificate` and `aws_acm_certificate_validation` in particular there is an example of using `aws_route53_record` to create the needed records in [the `aws_acm_certificate_validation` documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation):

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "example" {
  domain_name               = "example.com"
  subject_alternative_names = ["www.example.com", "example.org"]
  validation_method         = "DNS"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "example_com" {
  name         = "example.com"
  private_zone = false
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "example_org" {
  name         = "example.org"
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name    = dvo.resource_record_name
      record  = dvo.resource_record_value
      type    = dvo.resource_record_type
      zone_id = dvo.domain_name == "example.org" ? data.aws_route53_zone.example_org.zone_id : data.aws_route53_zone.example_com.zone_id
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "example" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.example.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.example : record.fqdn]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate_validation.example.certificate_arn
}
```

This example can work because the `aws_acm_certificate` resource type is designed so that the number of `domain_validation_options` elements is always known at plan time, and in particular that the `domain_name` attribute is also always known and thus is suitable to use as a map key in `for_each`.

Your example has the additional constraint of filtering out some of the elements, which you should be able to achieve by adding an `if` clause to the `for` expression and making sure that the result of that condition depends only on values that the AWS provider can know at planning time.

Comment: Hey Martin - thanks for the reply. So i had a very similar logic - except i refactored the for loop into a map in local, and then passed the map as a count. The difference in for_each sounds like a great suggestion, as i think the resolution may only happen during the apply.... will look to refactor from a count to for_each, thanks for the suggestion, will come back with confirmation if it worked.